# Displaying DIV from another ASPX page?

Tags: c#, html, gis

I'm developing a mapping application (`VS2008 C`#) and have my map window (Esri ADF MapControl) displayed within my main aspx.

I'm now compiling a print template with another aspx page which will display and print the current map from the main aspx.

Normally I'd use a Frame tag to dispay the main aspx in my print template however I'm just interested in copying over the map DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do it using jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
 body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
 </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script>
  $("#mydiv").load("mypage.html");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I specify a DIV within an ASPX to load? e.g... <script> $("#mydiv").load("mypage.aspx #DisplayDIV"); </script>

Comment: why not put ur aspx page as a user control (.ascx)

Comment: ah, really? I'm trying to use this but page loads blank...                                                      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: I'm developing localhost on a stand-alone box with no internet access so maybe it can't recognise the jquery library script URL?

Comment: yes off course, this url is being requested from jquery website :)

Comment: I've downloaded the Jquery .js file, included it my project and now I can post an image! The Div I need to display is within a table so presumably my code will have to change?

Comment: Can u try something like the code sample i posted in my answer

Comment: Ok, the Jquery script works perfectly. The issue is with the tool I'm trying to copy accross, it relies on other buddy controls etc to work. Thanks for all your help.